# Create multiple beans of the same Class in a dynamic and lazy manner

Tags: spring, spring-boot

```
@ConfigurationProperties("person")
public class PersonConfiguration {

    private List<Details> details = new ArrayList<>();

    //getters and setters and tostring

    public static class Details {
        private String key;
        private String company;
        private String family;

        //getters and setters and tostring

    }
}

public class Person {

    public String key;
    public SomeClass obj;

    //constructor

    //getter, setter and tostring
}

@Component
public class PersonFactory {

    @Autowired
    PersonConfiguration personConfig;

    public Person getPerson(String key) {
        //if key exists in PersonConfiguration
            //create SomeClass based on family and compnay details for corresponding key
            //create Person bean using key and SomeClass.
    }
}
```

How can i create multiple beans of Person in the above class in lazy manner only when requested based on the different keys in the request.

Basically have a configuration and factory class. Based on an incoming request need to check if it exists in the configuration and if it does, need to create an object of some type using factory class.

Comment: can you be more specific with example? @user

Comment: Want to create Person bean on the fly when some one calls PersonFactory.getPerson and add it to the applicationcontext